# Uniqueness of an embedded body extension in an algebraic closure

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let K be a field and $\Omega$ be a cloture ajgebre of field K. We consider $L/K$ and $L'/K$ are two finite extension of field such that $L\subset \Omega$ and $L'\subset \Omega$ such that $\deg(L/K)=\deg(L'/K)$.   Can we say that $L=L'$?

Comment: Take $K= \mathbb{Q}$, and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 3), L^{'} = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt 2)$

Comment: Can we say that this property is true for a finite field, that is: there is a unique extension of given degree $d$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ embedded in a fixed algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$?

Comment: For a finite field it is true. There is a single extension of degree d (up to homomorphism) which is the splitting field of $x^{p^{d}} -1$

Comment: the splitting field of $x^{p^d}−x$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.